# Hover Image Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, mousehover

I'd like to have a Simple Responsive HTML Index page , in which We see something like this : 
[image]

and then on hover it becomes like this :

[image]

But I want it to have an animation while changing to Urban Space Event , and then when I click on it it goes to another link.

Thanks

Comment: use css pseudo-class :hover

Comment: Here is plunker for you:
https://plnkr.co/edit/B1tWHQ8JcnQ586At24hL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
<img id="myImg" src=".." onclick="dosomething()">
```

CSS

```
#myImg{
/*your css*/
}

#myImg:hover{
/* animation*/
}
```